RxJs - Observable in service used within multiple pages. Need to trigger change detection manually
I've got observable in service, which is used by multiple pages. When observable value is changed on first page, then i go to the next page, subscription (on the second, current page) is not detecting any changes on this observable (which is logical), causing whole data flow to not being triggered. How to fix that, is there any proper way to manually trigger subscription to see changes?
Let's say that on both pages i filter data by setting "Min Cars" and "Max Cars" by simple user input, and these are two observables. Then i go to the next page, which subscribes to these two observables, and do some API calls, nothing is happening, subscription is not seeing any observable changes, but these values indeed are "new" - but new for the first page, not for the second one.

please share the minimal reproducible code

Do you subscribe inside the component and do something? Like updating some variable in the component you want to have updated?
Generally, i subscribe (i always have more than one thing to do with the updated data) and then i call markForCheck.
What i'm getting without any example, is that you are subscribing from something that its not a BehaviourSubject. Anything that its not a BehaviourSubject, you can't get the last emitted value.
If when the component load and there is anything to be done with a value that already exists in the "history", you have 2 options:

Save the value in the service and execute manually a verification on the component load
Change your observable to a BehaviourSubject


I also found that you can pipe the RxJs operator shareReplay on the original observable with a buffer of 1. $yourObservable.pipe(shareReplay(1)). This way you don't have to provide a default value for the subject.

@RobertRendell and then you always share the result observable from the pipe? Sounds interesting. I personally don't mind to have a initial value.
